# Implementing Where Not In using Eloquent Models not working

Tags: mysql, database, api, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to perform a query that displays only contents which are in table staff and table hr_validations but not in Table coo_validations.
Below is my laravel code:

```js
$loan = staff::select('staff_name','staff_id_fk','loan_amount','loan_tenor','hr_validations.id')
     ->join('hr_validations','hr_validations.staff_id_fk','=','staff.staff_id')
     ->whereNotIn('hr_validations.id','coo_validations.loan_id');
     return([$loan->pluck('staff_id_fk'), $loan->pluck('loan_amount'), $loan->pluck('loan_tenor'), $loan->pluck('hr_validations.id')]);
```

But it's returning an error ("invalid argument supplied for foreach"). Any help rendered would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is doesntHave() function of eloquent please see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 0):

you should pass an array for the values in whereNotIn:

```
->whereNotIn('hr_validations.id',['coo_validations.loan_id'])
```